# Integral of a L^1 function

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, lp-spaces, absolute-continuity

I have come across this inequality that is supposedly not true for $L^1(0,T)$ functions, but works for $g\in L^p(0,T), \, p>1$:
$$\forall \epsilon>0 \;\exists \delta>0 \; \text{s.t.} \;|\int_{t-\delta}^tg(s) ds|<\epsilon$$

How is that so?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is true that if $g$ is integrable ($\in L^1([0,T])$) then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $S \subset [0,T]$ with Lebesgue measure less than or equal to $\delta$ we have

$$\left|\int_S g(x) \, dx\right| < \epsilon.$$

This can be proved using the fact that $g$ can be approximated by a bounded simple function $\phi$ such that

$$\int_S |g(x) - \phi(x)| \, dx \leqslant \int_{[0,T]} |g(x) - \phi(x)| \, dx < \epsilon/2.$$

Since $\phi$ is bounded we have $|\phi(x)| \leqslant M$ and if $m(S) \leqslant \delta =  \epsilon/(2M)$, then

$$\int_S |\phi(x)| \, dx < M m(S) \leqslant \epsilon/2.$$

Thus,

$$\left|\int_S g(x) \, dx\right| \leqslant \int_S |g(x)| \, dx \leqslant \int_S |g(x) - \phi(x)| \, dx + \int_S |\phi(x)| \, dx < \epsilon.$$

In this case $S = [t - \delta,t]$ and $m(S) = \delta.$

Comment: Thanks! So I guess in case of a $g\in L^1(0,T;X)$ where $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space this proof still works; does it?

Comment: I assumed that $g$ is real valued as you did not specify. I have to think if it generalizes -- maybe not.

Comment: If $g:[0,T] \to X$ where $X$ is a Banach space, then $g$ can be approximated by simple functions such that $\int_{[0,T]} \| g - \phi \|_X$ is arbitrarily small. This generalizes from $X = \mathbb{R}$ so it should hold.

Comment: The other necessary property that $\| \int_S g \|_X \leqslant \int_S \|g\|_X$ is also true for a Banach space.

Comment: But it does require that $g$ be "Bochner integrable" meaning that $\|g\|_X$ is in $L^1$ as a real-valued function.